# BCP utility to create a format file, to import Excel data to SQL Server 2008 for BULK insertion

Tags: sql, excel, bcp, bulk, openrowset

Am trying to import Excel 2003 data into SQL table for SQL Server 2008.

Tried to add a linked server but have met with little success.

Now am trying to check if there's a way to use the BCP utility to do a BULK insert or BULK operation with OPENROWSET, using a format file to get the Excel mapping.

First of all, how can I create a format file for a table, that has differently named columns than the Excel spreadsheet colums?
Next, how to use this format file to import data from say a file at: C:\Folder1\Excel1.xsl
into table Table1 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's some examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178129.aspx) that demonstrate what the data file should look like (csv) and what the format file should look like. Unless you need to do this lots I'd just hand-craft the format file, save the excel data to csv, then try using bcp or OPENROWSET.

The format file specifies the column names for the destination. The data file doesn't have column headings so you don't need to worry about the excel (source) cols being different.

If you need to do more mapping etc, then create an SSIS package. You can use the data import wizard to get you started, then save as SSIS package, then edit to your heart's content.

If it's a one-off I'd use the SQL data import size, from right-click on database in mgmt studio. If you just have a few rows to import from excel I typically open a query to Edit Top 200 rows, edit the query to match the columns I have in excel, then copy and paste the rows from excel into SQL mgmt studio. Doesn't handle errors very well, but quick.